# Django HTML template database query doesn't show anything

Tags: django

I'm trying to query some data and insert it into my HTML template.

My model looks like this

```
class Usertasks(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    TaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And I have a view that has the following content

```
from callgolem.models import Usertasks

def dashboard(request):
    query_results = Usertasks.objects.all()
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/account/login/')
return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

and in my html template I wrote this

```
 <div class="tasks-list">
    <div>
      {% for item in query_results %}

          <p>{{ item.user }}</p>
          <p>{{ item.TaskID }}</p>
          <p>{{ item.TaskStatus }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
 </div>
```

However when i'm loading the webpage the query is blank. Nothing is shown. I opened my DBviewer and made sure that there's actual data in what im trying to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dashboard(request):
    query_results = Usertasks.objects.all()
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/account/login/')
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{'query_results':query_results})
```

change your view to this

Comment: Thank you very much! Will mark your answer correct in 9 minutes. Stack wont allow me to do it right now, since you're to quick! :-)